# What "pining and repining" meant in 17th century?

Tags: phrases

...like in : may be dying or even pining and repining" or "dragging the pining ang repining victim to the grave"?

Answer (score 2):

*Pine* has had a range of meanings, but in intransitive use it had by the middle of the 16th century pretty much settled down to the two fairly similar senses which survive today ([***OED***](http://archive.org/stream/oed07arch#page/878/mode/2up)):

> **5.** *intr.* To become wasted or feeble, from suffering (bodily or mental), esp. from intense grief, etc., wasting disease, or want of sustenance; to lose vitality or vigour; to languish, waste away.
>
> **6.** *intr.* To be consumed with longing; to languish with intense desire, to hunger after something; to long eagerly.

*Repine* has had since its first appearance in the middle of the 16th century only one transitive meaning ([***OED***](http://archive.org/stream/newenglishdicpt108murruoft#page/468/mode/2up)):

> **1.** *intr.* To feel or manifest discontent or dissatisfaction; to fret, murmur, or complain.

This picture is a little complicated by the fact that since the middle of the 17th century the two words have occasionally been used for each other; but I think you can be fairly sure that a 17th century writer meant by *pine and repine* the same thing you would mean if you wrote it today: *languish and complain*.